# Calulated column displays html markup sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am experiencing an issue with a calculated column that presently returns html markup for the purpose of KPI in sharepoint 2013. It was working well, all of a sudden it started displaying the raw html tags. I dont know what to do. Is there a setting that had to be adjusted from site settings or what?

See my calculated markup on column Name: KPI, Datatype: Calculated, Datatype return for calculated field: Number

Code:

```
=IF(C_RemedialStatus=1,"<DIV style='font-weight:bold;  line-height:20%; align-center;font-size:50px; color:green;'>•</DIV>",IF(C_RemedialStatus=0,"<DIV style='font-weight:bold;  line-height:20%; align-center;font-size:50px; color:red;'>•</DIV>"))
```

I need someones help at this time.

Comment: I think you need to try JSLINK